# Division and Modulus in Java

Tags: java

Create a method names dividesEvenly(a,b) that can receive two integers, a and b, return true if a can be divided evenly by b. Return false otherwise.example : dividesEvenly(8, 4) ➞ true # 8/4 = 2 dividesEvenly(10, 2) ➞ false # 10/2 = 5

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: this is the question I think "even" is the answer

Answer (score 1):

This question is about the modulus operator, in java a % symbol, also known as the remainder operator.

See also [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

If "a" can be divided evenly by "b", the result of `a / b` will be an even number. You can then check this with a modulus operation.

Writing this as a method in java, you have

```
public boolean dividesEvenly(int a, int b) {
    int division = a / b;
    return division % 2 == 0;
}
```

These two steps are summarized as follows:

1. Divide a by b and assign this value to a variable (called "division" in the code)
2. Check that if this division were divided by two it would have no remainder (division mod 2 equals zero). If this is the case, then it divides evenly. Otherwise (division mod 2 not zero) the result of the division is an odd number.

Comment: Note that `dividesEvenly(10, 2)` is supposed to return `false`.

Comment: @Izruo thanks, I missed that, I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry i don't get it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the modulo `%` opperator. To check whether a number, in your case `a/b`, is even you can do this: `(a/b)%2 == 0`

The complete methode would lock something like this:

```
public boolean dividesEvenly(int a, int b) {
    return (a/b)%2==0;
}
```